# How to create immediately invoked functions (blocks) in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I need to create a self-executing block in Swift, similar to what we had in Objective C:

```
{
  /* statements */
}
```

However the same construct in Swift yields "braced block of statements in unused block".

Comment: Your (Objective-)C example is *not* a block and *not* a "immediately invoked function" or "self-executing block". It is just parentheses introducing a local scope. If that is what you are looking for then your question is a duplicate. – If your question is about ["Immediately-invoked function expressions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) then @jrturtons's answer should answer it. – Perhaps you can clarify your question and/or title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, I use:

```
if true {
  /* ... */
}
```

Any better solution is welcome.

**UPDATE 2**: Swift 2 now has a new control structure `do`:

```
do {
    /* ... */
}
```

**UPDATE**: Another answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011271/how-to-create-local-scopes-in-swift):

```
func locally(work: () -> ()) {
    work()
}

...

locally {
    /* ... */
}
```

This looks nice, except that due to Swift's rules, you have to use `self.property` instead of just `property` inside the block.

Comment: I think this is the best you can get. Objective-C like scope block is not possible as the syntax is taken by the closures.