# Why does Swift 1.2 reduce force me to use the combine: argument name?

Tags: swift

This code was legal in Swift 1.1:

```
let arr = Array(1...100)
let sum = arr.reduce(0,+)
```

But in Swift 1.2 it is no longer legal. Instead, I am compelled to use the `combine:` parameter name explicitly:

```
let arr = Array(1...100)
let sum = arr.reduce(0,combine:+)
```

Why? I see no difference in their declarations — except for the new `@noescape` attribute (well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28428521/341994)). But why should *that* change anything about the use of external parameter names?

Comment: I wonder why it compiled before, the Swift 1.2 behavior seems to be correct.

Comment: @MartinR That possibility (maybe Swift 1.1 and before behavior was the bug) occurred to me as well. Maybe Swift 1.1 was thinking: "Well, this is the last parameter and it can be a trailing closure, so the parameter name is always omissible", while Swift 1.2 is thinking, "It is omissible only if it really _is_ a trailing closure."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I filed a bug report on this, and Apple replied that the change was intentional. In my view, being able to say `reduce(0,+)` was elegant and pithy, so the API for `reduce` should declare the external parameter name unnecessary. In Apple's stated view, the `combine:` external parameter name clarifies the purpose of the parameter. We have agreed to disagree.

Comment: that's really interesting, seeing as they seemingly decided not to enforce that with the general `reduce` function (see my answer below). A little inconsistent.

Comment: I know - I told them that in my bug report. They basically blew me off. If you support my argument based on this inconsistency, I wish you'd file a bug too.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `reduce` function for sequences—they aren't forcing the `combine:` parameter name there.

```
reduce(1...5, 0, +)
```

Comment: True but irrelevant. I'm specifically asking about _this_ `reduce`, not _that_ `reduce`.