# Xcode skips my entire code inside autoreleasepool in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have recently figured out that the screenshot code uses ~140Mb of temp memory when taking a screenshot that results in a 4MB JPEG. So I enclosed my screenshot code in a autoreleasepool as below in SWIFT

```
    autoreleasepool{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cgSizeToUse, false, 0)
        webView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
```

But now when I debug, the code inside the autoreleasepool is skipped entirely. This is the only autoreleasepool in my code. Any thoughts on what is ahppening?

Comment: "the code inside the autoreleasepool is skipped entirely" How do you know?

Comment: Walk through of the code under debugger. I can see the control reach the line "autoreleasepool{" and when I hit the next button in debugger, the control reaches the end of the autoreleasepool. And I have code to verify if the screenshot was taken

Comment: Ah. But what if you put a breakpoint on the first line inside the autoreleasepool, and just run? Do you or do you not eventually hit that breakpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form `statement {...}` is actually a statement followed by a <strike>block</strike> closure.

The <strike>block</strike> closure really is running, but the debugger treats it as a single statement in and of itself.   Set a breakpoint on the first line inside the block and you'll be able to step through the <strike>block</strike> closure.

This is the declaration for `autoreleasepool`:

```
func autoreleasepool(code: @noescape () -> ())
```

As it takes only a single closure as an argument, then we are free to drop the parens and use a trailing closure.

See the answers to this question for an explanation of `@noescape`: [@noescape attribute in Swift 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427436/noescape-attribute-in-swift-1-2)

*Edited because Objective-C graybeard got the nomenclature wrong.*

Answer (score 3):

The code inside the `autoreleasepool` block *does* run. It's just that your method of *determining* whether or not it runs is misleading you.