# Must all variable or lazy variable initializer in Swift include weak self?

Tags: closures, swift3

I have seen a lot of code that uses closure to initialize a var or lazy var which refer to self without the weak self syntax. Doesn't that create a risk of a retain cycle? Why doesn't the compiler flag that? Should it be a mandatory thing to always use weak self or unowned self when using closure of any kind as a safety measure?

e.g.

```
class Test {
  lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    return tableView
  }
}()
```

Comment: Related: [Lazy initialisation and retain cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38141298/2976878)

Answer (score 11):

Lazy variables that aren't closure properties are not retained by anything so there is no need to use `[unowned self]` here:

```
class Test {
    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {

        let tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        return tableView
    }()
}
```

This is not to be confused with closure properties that are lazily defined! Then the closure captures self, which will create a retain cycle. In this case you are creating a strong reference via self.view.bounds so you should use `[unowned self]` (you know in this case that the tableView shouldn't exist if the Test object doesn't).

```
class Test {
    lazy var tableView: () -> UITableView = {
        [unowned self] in

        let tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self    
        return tableView
    }
}
```

Further reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

Comment: It seems like the syntax changed in later versions of Swift, is this still valid?