# Initializing property via closure

Tags: swift, closures

I've observed that people sometimes using closures to initialize properties. e.g. instead of

```
lazy var test1: String = String("a string")
```

they use

```
lazy var test2: String = { String("a string") }()
```

What is the benefit/convenience in using closure to initialize property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two do the same work. Closure initialization comes handy when you need extra code to configure property object. E.g.:

```
lazy var point: CGPoint = {
    let x = ...
    let y = ...
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, if there is no extra work needed for the lazy variable after the initialization for it, it would be enough do declare it *without* the closure initialization.

For instance, for a simple string it is fair to implement:

```
lazy var myString = "a string"
```

However, when it comes to something needs more editing (setup) -like `CLLocationManager` for instance-, you would naturally go with the closure initialization:

```
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    var lm = CLLocationManager()

    // here is one extra thing to do:
    lm.delegate = self
    return lm
}()
```

As mentioned, at some point we needed to do additional step(s) after the initialization (which is `lm.delegate = self` in the above example).

Referring to your case, since there is nothing should happen after the initialization, both:

```
lazy var test1: String = String("a string")
```

and

```
lazy var test2: String = { String("a string") }()
```

are the same. You should go with the first one as a shorthand typing.

Comment: @AhmadF, the closure immediately applied because of `()` at the end. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144190/2463616