# Why does closure capture reference while function does not? Also, why "lazy" keyword is required for closure declaration?

Tags: swift, function, closures, lazy-evaluation, conceptual

I experimented it with the following code in Xcode Playground:

```
class X {

    var a = 3

    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(self.a) is deallocated.")
    }

    func returnX() -> Int {
        return self.a
    }

    lazy var anotherReturnX: () -> Int = {
        return self.a
    }
}

var e: X? = X(a: 6)
print(e!.returnX())
e = nil // prints "6 is deallocated."

var f: X? = X(a: 7)
print(f!.anotherReturnX())
f = nil // prints nothing
```

From the above code, I can see that no reference is captured in the function `returnX()`, thus `e` is deallocated once I set `e` to `nil`. However, a reference is captured in the closure `anotherReturnX()`, thus `f` is not deallocated. Apparently, this implies that a closure captures references while a function does not.

Additionally, when I first type out the code, I didn't include `lazy` keyword before the closure declaration, as I thought it would be unnecessary to do so. However it triggers a compile-time error. I infer that since the closure can only be accessed after instantiation, it *must* access to the instantiated `self`. But since what I am declaring here is effectively an "anonymous function", why would the closure access to `self` during instantiation anyway?

After putting in some thoughts, I found more contradictions. For instance, I understand that a reference is captured when a closure is called. However, during initialisation of `X`, I am simply *assigning* a closure to a variable *without calling it*, same as the declaration of other instance properties. Thus the closure should not do anything during initialisation, and compiling the code without keyword `lazy` should be fine. But compilation fails. I am not sure what goes wrong in my understanding.

I have read some related articles, such as strong/weak reference, retain cycle, lazy stored property. However, many explain "what happens" and do not say much about "why".

So other than the question raised in the title, I would also like to clarify, what makes function and closure different from each other such that the above situation happens?

Update:

The fact that closure captures reference while function does not is further "enforced" on me, since, according to the Xcode Compiler, I can rewrite `return self.a` as `return a` in `returnX()`, but I cannot do so in `anotherReturnX`. As such, I guess I would have to accept that, although function and closure are similar because each of them is "a bundle of functionalities", function *is* different from closure that it does not capture references. If I were to go deeper in the reason behind this, it would probably involve the design of Swift itself?

However, I still cannot understand why `lazy` keyword is required for closure declaration.

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141553/5519329. It might help to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
lazy var anotherReturnX: () -> Int = {
    return self.a
}
```

The self here is a strong self.
When an object references another object strongly, ARC cant deallocate so a retain cycle is created. The reference should be weak to avoid a retain cycle by creating weak self inside the block.

```
lazy var anotherReturnX: () -> Int = { [weak self] in
    return self?.a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`returnX` is a method of the class. Methods don't capture variables. `self` is an implicit local variable in methods, that is implicitly passed to the method when the method is called.

`anotherReturnX` is a property that is assigned a closure lazily. That closure captures outside variables that are used within it, including `self`. That capturing creates a strong reference from the closure to the `X` instance, which, combined with the strong reference from the `X` instance to the closure, creates a retain cycle.