# What is the equivalent in Swift of this snippet?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I found this code in Objective-c and was wondering what is the equivalent of it in Swift.

```
CGContextSaveGState(context)
{
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, yOffset);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, yOffset);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

What bothers me here are the two braces { }

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [How to create local scopes in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011271/how-to-create-local-scopes-in-swift) ?

Comment: I was actually looking what it means but thanks for the link

Comment: This is not valid Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual need for those braces. This is a coding technique—[you can read a post that touches on it here](http://www.notesfromandy.com/2011/07/31/double-braces-for-startend-blocks/)—that makes these start/do something/end blocks a little easier to read, but the code is basically equivalent to:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context)
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, yOffset);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, yOffset);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

...without the braces. (And that code is exactly the same in Swift as it is in Objective C.)

The only difference is that [the braces define a variable scope in your original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500006/what-is-the-purpose-of-anonymous-blocks-in-c-style-languages), but there's no practical difference in this case.

As far as I can tell, there's no directly equivalent structure in Swift, which doesn't have these "anonymous blocks" (i.e. sections of code within braces, not actual [Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html).) However, you can find [some explorations of ways of doing it in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011271/how-to-create-local-scopes-in-swift).

Comment: Thanks. I saw indeed I could simply write it down without braces but was wondering...

Comment: Just an addition: These "anonymous blocks" are called compound statement.

Answer (score -1):

The code would be practically the same.
Please, check out Apple's Documentation for further reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I couldn't find the same kind of example. What bothers me here are the two braces { }. Looks like a block but I'm not sure as I don't really know Objective-c

Comment: @Nico: It would be useful if you add that information to your question, so that people know what you are actually asking.